# Converting Buffered Image to MultipartFile

Tags: java, image, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC & JSP

My scenario-

User uploads image file (gif,jpg,png) and if the file doesnt match dimensions then file needs to be scaled and disaply on jsp as preview.

I have `MultipartFile`(which is uploaded file), I convert that into `BufferedImage` then I resize the BufferedImage using `Graphics2D`. I want to convert this buffered image into multipart file again to show it on jsp.

How Can i convert buffered image into MultipartFile?

Thanks

Comment: Try to describe what you want to do with the image. You probably don't need to convert it back to `MultipartFile`. Do you want to store it (on file? in db?)? Do you want display a JSP with the image in a JSP tag? Or do you simply want to return the rescaled image in the response from your service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this statement is correct: *I want to convert this buffered image into multipart file again to show it on jsp*

To my knowledge you need to either:

1. Write the converted image into a disk and display it using html `<img..>` tag, or
2. Create a spring mvc handler method that writes the image into the response body directly, something like this

.

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public void convertedImg(HttpServletResponse resp) {
  // set response Content-Type..
  OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
  //.. write your converted image into os
}
```

Comment: That said you can store it into a Blob binary format into your database. Then you would need to either display it directly from this format or convert it to another object (e.g: MultipartFile) for several purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `ImageIO` to write your `BufferedImage` to some file format.

Like:

```
BufferedImage image; // your image
OutputStream stream; // your output

try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", stream);
}
finally {
    stream.flush();
}
```

Where `stream` can be a `FileOutputStream` to the server's file system, the `OutputStream` of a database blob, or the servlet response's `OutputStream`, depending on where/if you want to store it.